# Not authorised to view page admin

Tags: routes, users

So I am following the book Drupal 7 Pro Development book and just completed chapter 2. I cannot access my modules admin page. Here is my menu hook. Can you please point me in the right direction.

```
function annotate_menu(){

 //Makes category
 $items['admin/config/annotate'] = array (
 'title' => 'Node Annotation',
 'description' => 'Adjust node annotation options',
 'position' => 'right',
 'weight' => -5,
 'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page', //function from system settings.
 'access arguements' => array('administer site configuration'), //who can see this.
 'file' => 'system.admin.inc', //file where callback function is called
 'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'), //get system module path
 );


 //Makes menu under category
 $items['admin/config/annotate/settings'] = array (
 'title' => 'Annotation Settings',
 'description' => 'Change how annotations behave',
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //function called
 'page arguements' => array('annotate_admin_settings'), //formID which is function name in annotate.admin.inc
 'access arguements' => array('administer site configuration'), //who can access settings
 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 'file' => 'annotate.admin.inc', //file where formID is located.
 );

 return $items;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just spelt 'arguments' wrong in both of the 'access arguments' and 'page arguments' properties.

At least one of 'access callback' or 'access arguments' needs to be present in the router item or you won't be able to access the page.

Just fix that spelling, clear the cache, and it should work fine

Comment: I feel such a idiot right now :P Also now I am getting a HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error), When a click the settings link.

Comment: Everyone's done that at least once, any programmer who tells you different is lying! I would post the second error as a separate question and perhaps show your page callback code, it should hopefully be obvious where the problem is then

Comment: Congratulations on good eyes. I missed his spelling mistake and code he posted looked perfectly OK to me, so I was sure problem must be elsewhere :D

Comment: God the amount of hours I spent debugging a Javascript code only to have realized I spelt `behaviors` as `behaviours` ... curse of the British English...